# How to use the same function for different buttons to display their own dropdown lists

Tags: javascript, html

I am going to have multiple dropdown buttons to show their own dropdown lists. In HTML, the dropdown lists are the sibling elements of buttons. When I use the querySelector and click whichever button, the first buttons dropdown list shows up naturally. Which selector should I use instead or any other solutions? How can I use buttonDropdown() function for each button?
Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="container">
    <button class="dropdown-button">
        <!-- content -->
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-button-list">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
</div>

const dropdownButton = document.querySelector('.dropdown-button')

dropdownButton.addEventListener('click', showDropdown)

function showDropdown() {
    document.querySelector.('dropdown-button-list').classList.add('show')
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more details so we can help you, please check the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also check out the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), it would be even more helpful if you can provide a working example with the code you've tried so far so also check [Minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you associate them together inside of an element (like I used `class='dropdown-group'`) then you can easily find the associated list to the button by utilizing an event listener and

```
evt.target.closest('.dropdown-group').querySelector('.dropdown-button-list')
```

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-button').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', e => buttonDropdown))
      })

    function buttonDropdown(evt) {
      // button is evt.target
      // associated dropdown is:
      // evt.target.closest('.dropdown-group').querySelector('.dropdown-button-list')
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='dropdown-group'>
    <button class="dropdown-button">
                    <!-- content -->
                </button>
    <div class="dropdown-button-list">
      <!-- content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but this didn't work for me. I get "event.target.closest is not a function" error. I am sure that there is no typo in class names etc. Sorry, I am new to JavaScript so would it be possible for you to make a simple description about how I could use event.target properly?

Comment: actually that was confusing. don't worry about that one line in my description. Utilize the code and the extra div tag from my answer that are in the snippet